# In infragistics xamdatagrid how to select a row on right click

Tags: infragistics, xamdatagrid

In the XAML, I have this code

```
<igDP:FieldLayout.FieldSettings>
    <igDP:FieldSettings AllowRecordFiltering="True" CellClickAction="SelectRecord" AllowEdit="False"/>
</igDP:FieldLayout.FieldSettings>
```

Here, the CellClickAction is for the left click. Is there some corresponding Action for the right click as well to select the record. I want the record to be selected both on the left and the right click

Comment: Could somebody please help

Comment: There is an answer to this on the Infragistics forums: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/50707/266205.aspx

Answer (score 1):

create a Style for the DataRecordPresenter (the DataRecord’s visual element) with an EvenSetter like for the MouseRightButtonDown event like this one:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordPresenter}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Handler="DataRecordPresenter_MouseRightButtonDown" />
</Style>
```

and use this code snippets in its event handler:

```
void DataRecordPresenter_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Clear previous selcted rows        
    (sender as DataRecordPresenter).Record.IsSelected = true;
}
```

There is one problem here: if you continue right click on rows/cell in different row it selects multiple rows. So clear any previous selection then it will work.

Comment: The command to clear would be `dataGrid.ExecuteCommand(DataPresenterCommands.ClearAllSelected);` if `dataGrid` is the name of your grid control.